# Rerouting traffic from port 80 to another port on a single ip

Tags: port-forwarding, iptables, node.js

I have a server with multiple IP addresses associated with it.  I'm trying to run a node.js web server (which I do not want to run as root), using only one of those ip addresses (it would be very bad if the traffic from all the ip addresses were forwarded).

Through searching superuser, it looked like this could be possible with iptables:

[How to setting up iptables for traffic fowarding on port 80 from specific sources](https://superuser.com/questions/147766/how-to-setting-up-iptables-for-traffic-fowarding-on-port-80-from-specific-source)

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 --source 212.333.111.222 -j REDIRECT --to-port 9020
```

However, I do not understand why eth0 is needed.

According to:

http://blog.softlayer.com/2011/iptables-tips-and-tricks-port-redirection/

this could be done with:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2525 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 25
```

What is the correct way of forwarding traffic from a single ip on port 80,
lets say 111.111.111.111:80 to another port on the same server, lets say 111.111.111.111:8765?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8765`

Instead of using IP address use interface name, I mean instead of `eth0` you can use the interface you want.

This rule says iptables:

1. Do it on PreRouting
2. Do nat
3. On interface eth0
4. Protocol is TCP
5. Destination port to match is 80
6. Redirect it to port 8765

Comment: After doing this, I am still not able to access my web server on port 80 - accessing it from port 8765 still works, so I know my node.js server is still up and listening, but the requests and responses don't seem to be forwarded from 8765 to port 80.Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Can you send me `tcpdump` output?

Comment: Unfortunately there are way too many other sites running, making the tcpdump hard to decipher - I didn't see anything specific to this ip, though.  I tried checking iptables with -L - but couldn't find my rule we just added.  Could something stop new rules?

Comment: To see if your rule added you should use this command: `iptables -L -t nat`

Comment: Thanks for your help, Hamed - I've ended up going a different route using nginx, however I will make note of this for the future.